# Qual nome do plugin do sublime t 2/3 que indica erro de sintaxe na linguagem php?

Tags: php, sublime-text

Preciso saber algum plugin do sublime text 3 que ele indica erro na sintaxe do código tipo debuger real-time igual o que tem no phpStorm... alguém sabe?

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHP%20Syntax%20Checker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O plugin mais popular é o XDebug

https://xdebug.org/

Veja também o uso pelo netbeans:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug